# If $f(z)^3$ is analytic then $f(z)$ is analytic.Is it true?if yes prove it.otherwise give counterexample.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)^3$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}$ then $f(z)$ is analytic.Is it true?if yes prove it.otherwise give counterexample.

Comment: What about $f(z)=\sqrt[3]z$? $f(z)^3=z$ is clearly analytic on $\mathbb C$, but what about $f'(0)$?

Answer (score 10):

Since there is no continuity requirement for $f(z)$, just pick your favourite non-zero analitic function $g(z)$ and solve $f(z)^3=g(z)$. At almost all points you have three choices and you can easily make it non analytic.

E.g. Let $1, \omega, \omega^2$ be the three roots of unity. Define $f$ to be sometimes $1$, sometimes $\omega$... Then $f$ cannot be analytic, but $f^3$ is constant....

Comment: Oh, your example is the one. And I was bothering considering the log... +1.

Comment: However, if $f$ is *continuous* and $f^3$ analytic, then $f$ is analytic except possibly at its zeroes.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. And it is easy to construct examples where $f$ is continuous, but it is not analytic at its zeroes....

Answer (score 0):

N.S. answer is from far the best possible answer here. But I wrote this and it works, so I guess I'll leave it here.

Let $\log$ be the principal branch of the complex logarithm. It is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ and does not admit any analytic continuation beyond that.

Now set
$$
f(z):=e^{\frac{\log z}{3}}.
$$
Again, this is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ and does not admit any analytic continuation beyond that. Not even a continuous extension (except at $0$).
For instance, you have
$$
\lim_{\theta\rightarrow \pi^+}\log(e^{i\theta})=i\pi\qquad \lim_{\theta\rightarrow \pi^-}\log(e^{i\theta})=-i\pi.
$$
So
$$ 
\lim_{\theta\rightarrow \pi^+}f(e^{i\theta})=e^{i\pi/3}\neq e^{-i\pi/3}=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow \pi^-}f(e^{i\theta}).
$$
So there is no analytic continuation at $-1=e^{i\pi}$.

Yet 
$$
f(z)^3=z
$$
admits an analytic continuation on $\mathbb{C}$.